# Maven - Exclude a specific dependency using build profile

Tags: maven, openjdk-11

Based on JDK11 restructuring of `tools.jar` I was trying to exclude it from a POM dependency as follows

```
<profile>
    <id>exclude-if-jdk11</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>11</jdk>
    </activation>
    <properties>
       <!-- bla bla bla -->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.internal.mypomz</groupId>
    <artifactId>mypomext</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</profile>
```

Despite the above, I am getting the error that tools.jar cannot be found in `JDK11/bin` folder. But I was expecting that this jar lookup will be skipped. Is there something I've configured incorrectly?

Comment: Have a look at `mvn dependency:tree` with and without the profile activated.

Comment: I would suggest to refactor your code and get rid of tools things like this...and solve it at the root not via exclusion...furthermore your dependency is of type `pom` which does not has dependencies only a jar can have dependencies ...and having profiles for different dependencies is in general a bad idea...

Comment: @khmarbaise        One step at a time... :) Also, we are not having profile for dependencies, the profile is active only when we have JDK11 on the platform. So it's not that brittle. I agree with what you said about exclusions, hence, removed them entirely without profiles.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging, we found out that there was a war dependency which was also fetching `tools.jar`. So yes, the fix was using `mvn dependency:tree` first we checked who is fetching the jars. Then exclude them individually, until `mvn dependency:tree` shows no evidence of that.

We got it to work with both JDK11 and JDK8. Also, as update to the `profile` body posted in the question, we have now excluded all `tools.jar` from the POM and it is more manageable.